# When writing a research paper, what is the acceptable format for acknowledging my advisor?

Tags: mathematical-writing, paper-request, research

I am writing a paper for an independent study course I am enrolled in. I have contributed all of the work to the project. My supervisor has been a guiding force during this research, suggesting things here and there. These suggestions haven't changed the fundamental focus of the project.

When discussing relevance to other subject areas or contributions, is it better form to say we/us or I? Do I give him credit directly in the paper, or in the acknowledgements?

Comment: you will want to discuss this with your advisor, even suggesting the co-author option.

Comment: In a research paper it is customary to use "we" rather than "I", but this does not imply there is more than one of you.

Comment: The problem better fits [Academia StackExchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Robert Israel: I do not think this applies to acknowledgement. When we write "we", we mean "the author and the reader", for example: "
Let us set $x=0$". But in the acknowledgement this sounds strange. There is also an impersonal form: "The author thanks...".

Comment: If your advisor declines to be a co-author, giving an acknowledgement for his/her guidance would be the best way. Also, I agree that it's better to use "we", and even if you acknowledge your advisor, as long as the paper only has 1 author, people will give you credit.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: It may be common among some authors, but it's also very strange, or at least that's what we think.

Comment: @ChristianRemling [Author's "we"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism#pluralis_modestiae)

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've spoken with other professors as well and they suggested acknowledgement, or even simplifying the paper so that later versions can include a co-author. Is there an admin who can port this over the the Academia Stack?